# ProFTPD Version 1.3.5d ExtendedLog is not working?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, proftpd

I am a beginner in Linux. I am using Plesk onyx with 17.5.3 Ubuntu 16.04 1705170317.16. My ExtendedLog configured in /etc/proftpd.conf is not working.

Following is my /etc/proftpd.conf

```
#
 # To have more informations about Proftpd configuration
 # look at : http://www.proftpd.org/
 #

 # This is a basic ProFTPD configuration file (rename it to
 # 'proftpd.conf' for actual use.  It establishes a single server
 # and a single anonymous login.  It assumes that you have a user/group
 # "nobody" and "ftp" for normal operation and anon.

 ServerName                      "ProFTPD"
 #ServerType                     standalone ServerType                      inetd DefaultServer                   on LogFormat nijin "%t %h %u %D
 %f \"%r\" %s %b" ExtendedLog /var/log/ftp.log ALL nijin <Global
 DefaultRoot     ~               psacln AllowOverwrite          on
 <IfModule mod_tls.c
         # common settings for all virtual hosts
         TLSEngine on
         TLSRequired off

         TLSLog /var/log/plesk/ftp_tls.log

         TLSRSACertificateFile /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/httpsd.pem
         TLSRSACertificateKeyFile /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/httpsd.pem

         # Authenticate clients that want to use FTP over TLS?
         TLSVerifyClient off

         # Allow SSL/TLS renegotiations when the client requests them, but
         # do not force the renegotations.  Some clients do not support
         # SSL/TLS renegotiations; when mod_tls forces a renegotiation, these
         # clients will close the data connection, or there will be a timeout
         # on an idle data connection.
         TLSRenegotiate none

         # As of ProFTPD 1.3.3rc1, mod_tls only accepts SSL/TLS data connections
         # that reuse the SSL session of the control connection, as a security measure.
         # Unfortunately, there are some clients (e.g. curl) which do not reuse SSL sessions.
         TLSOptions NoSessionReuseRequired </IfModule PassivePorts 50001 50100 </Global DefaultTransferMode     binary UseFtpUsers      
 on

 TimesGMT                        off SetEnv TZ :/etc/localtime
 # Port 21 is the standard FTP port. Port                            21
 # Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new dirs and files
 # from being group and world writable. Umask                           022

 # To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
 # to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
 # at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
 # in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
 # that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
 # (such as xinetd) MaxInstances                    30

 #Following part of this config file were generate by PSA automatically
 #Any changes in this part will be overwritten by next manipulation
 #with Anonymous FTP feature in PSA control panel.

 #Include directive should point to place where FTP Virtual Hosts configurations
 #preserved

 ScoreboardFile /var/run/proftpd_scoreboard

 # Primary log file mest be outside of system logrotate province

 TransferLog /var/log/plesk/xferlog

 #Change default group for new files and directories in vhosts dir to psacln

 <Directory /var/www/vhosts
         GroupOwner      psacln </Directory

 # Enable PAM authentication AuthPAM on AuthPAMConfig proftpd

 IdentLookups off UseReverseDNS off

 AuthGroupFile   /etc/group

 Include /etc/proftpd.d/*.conf
```

This is my customized configuration file. Added ExtendedLog /var/log/ftp.log in my configuration file. But extended log /var/log/ftp.log is not created yet. I touch this file manually but no use, logs are not populating.

Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: What does `ls -ald /var/log` show?  What about `ls -al /var/log/ftp.log`?  ProFTPD is particular about the permissions on logging directories, if they are too open, it will refuse to write log files there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set non-world writable permissions to  /var/log/ftp.log as it recommended at http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_ExtendedLog.html

I have tested it by the following steps and it worked:

1. echo `"ExtendedLog /var/log/ftp.log read,write" >> /etc/proftpd.conf`
2. touch `/var/log/ftp.log` && `chmod 644 /var/log/ftp.log`
3. upload a test file
4. check the log:`root@server:/# cat  /var/log/ftp.log
   192.168.34.219 UNKNOWN mario [14/Jun/2017:11:38:20 +0700] "STOR Google Chrome.lnk" 226 2356`

Answer (score 0):

Update: the permissions were set to 664